# virt-install aarch64 vm on amd64 host failed

Tags: qemu, arm64

### background

I was going to install a aarch64-ubuntu VM on my centos 7.5 Host.

Installation of qemu-aarch64 and virt is cool.

Also config default pool by CMD `virsh pool-define-as --name default --type dir --target /data/qemu/guest_images`

When I type this `virt-install --name ubuntu--aarch64 --ram 4096 --arch aarch64 --boot uefi --disk size=20 --cdrom /data/qemu/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso` and follow TUI, an error came out:

[image]

[image]

The crash log is `/var/crash/1631687637.154057503.block_probe_fail.crash`, then I typed `cat /var/crash/1631687637.154057503.block_probe_fail.crash | grep 'ERROR' -A 10 -B 10`, got this:

```
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,648 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Refresh/configure_snapd: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,650 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Refresh/configure_snapd/get_details: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,720 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Refresh/check_for_update: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:37,626 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Install/install: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:37,761 DEBUG subiquity.server.controllers.snaplist:59 loading list of snaps
 2021-09-15 06:33:37,818 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Filesystem/_probe: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:37,947 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Refresh/check_for_update: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:37,977 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/SnapList/loader: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:37,988 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: restricted=False
 2021-09-15 06:33:38,054 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:826 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): geoip.ubuntu.com
 2021-09-15 06:33:38,767 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Refresh/check_for_update: FAIL: cancelled
 2021-09-15 06:33:38,913 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/SnapList/loader/list: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:39,795 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:40,153 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "cloud_init_ok": tr...
 2021-09-15 06:33:41,258 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:38 +0000] "GET /meta/status?cur=null HTTP/1.1" 200 417 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:41,544 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:396 http://localhost:None "GET /v2/snaps/subiquity HTTP/1.1" 200 975
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,030 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,209 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "cloud_init_ok": tr...
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,290 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:38 +0000] "GET /meta/status?cur=null HTTP/1.1" 200 417 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,467 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/Refresh/configure_snapd/get_details: SUCCESS: current version of snap is: '21.08.2'
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,537 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Refresh/configure_snapd/switching: switching subiquity to stable/ubuntu-20.04.3
--
 2021-09-15 06:33:54,649 DEBUG subiquitycore.utils:48 run_command called: ['ssh-keygen', '-lf', '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key']
 2021-09-15 06:33:55,604 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:396 https://geoip.ubuntu.com:443 "GET /lookup HTTP/1.1" 200 None
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,263 DEBUG subiquitycore.utils:61 run_command ['ssh-keygen', '-lf', '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key'] exited with code 0
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,477 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/ssh_info_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"username": "installer", "password_kind": "KNOWN", "password": "FRbjgB3iY7r7...
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,549 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:49 +0000] "GET /meta/ssh_info HTTP/1.1" 200 642 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,611 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Locale/GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,631 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/Locale/GET: SUCCESS: 200 "C.UTF-8"
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,682 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:49 +0000] "GET /locale HTTP/1.1" 200 200 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,807 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/Refresh/configure_snapd/switching: SUCCESS: switched to stable/ubuntu-20.04.3
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,830 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/Refresh/configure_snapd: SUCCESS: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,968 ERROR block-discover:332 block probing failed restricted=False
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/snap/subiquity/2654/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py", line 325, in _probe
     await asyncio.wait_for(self._probe_once_task.task, 15.0)
   File "/snap/subiquity/2654/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 362, in wait_for
     raise futures.TimeoutError()
 concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,130 DEBUG subiquitycore.common.errorreport:384 generating crash report
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,249 INFO subiquitycore.common.errorreport:407 saving crash report 'block probing crashed with TimeoutError' to /var/crash/1631687637.154057503.block_probe_fail.crash
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,329 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: FAIL: cancelled
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,354 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/ErrorReporter/1631687637.154057503.block_probe_fail/add_info: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,391 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: restricted=True
InstallerServerLogInfo:
 2021-09-15 06:33:02,970 INFO subiquity:102 Starting Subiquity server revision 2654
 2021-09-15 06:33:02,990 INFO subiquity:103 Arguments passed: ['/snap/subiquity/2654/usr/bin/subiquity-server']
 2021-09-15 06:33:04,266 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:04 +0000] "GET /meta/status HTTP/1.1" 200 425 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:04,358 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:04 +0000] "GET /meta/status HTTP/1.1" 200 425 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,114 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/apply_autoinstall_config: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,565 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/apply_autoinstall_config: SUCCESS: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,579 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "cloud_init_ok": tr...
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,601 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:04 +0000] "GET /meta/status?cur=%22CLOUD_INIT_WAIT%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 417 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,611 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "cloud_init_ok": tr...
 2021-09-15 06:33:36,633 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:04 +0000] "GET /meta/status?cur=%22CLOUD_INIT_WAIT%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 417 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:38,767 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Refresh/check_for_update: FAIL: cancelled
 2021-09-15 06:33:39,795 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:40,153 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "cloud_init_ok": tr...
 2021-09-15 06:33:41,258 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:38 +0000] "GET /meta/status?cur=null HTTP/1.1" 200 417 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,030 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,209 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "cloud_init_ok": tr...
 2021-09-15 06:33:42,290 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:38 +0000] "GET /meta/status?cur=null HTTP/1.1" 200 417 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:43,310 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:43,578 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/client_variant_POST: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:43,841 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/client_variant_POST: SUCCESS: 200 null
 2021-09-15 06:33:44,116 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:43 +0000] "POST /meta/client_variant?variant=%22server%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 195 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:44,282 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/client_variant_POST: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:44,512 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/client_variant_POST: SUCCESS: 200 null
 2021-09-15 06:33:45,115 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:43 +0000] "POST /meta/client_variant?variant=%22server%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 195 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:45,339 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:49,797 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/Meta/ssh_info_GET: 
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,477 INFO root:39 finish: subiquity/Meta/ssh_info_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"username": "installer", "password_kind": "KNOWN", "password": "FRbjgB3iY7r7...
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,549 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:49 +0000] "GET /meta/ssh_info HTTP/1.1" 200 642 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,682 INFO aiohttp.access:206  [15/Sep/2021:06:33:49 +0000] "GET /locale HTTP/1.1" 200 200 "-" "Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0"
 2021-09-15 06:33:56,968 ERROR block-discover:332 block probing failed restricted=False
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/snap/subiquity/2654/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py", line 325, in _probe
     await asyncio.wait_for(self._probe_once_task.task, 15.0)
   File "/snap/subiquity/2654/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 362, in wait_for
     raise futures.TimeoutError()
 concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,249 INFO subiquitycore.common.errorreport:407 saving crash report 'block probing crashed with TimeoutError' to /var/crash/1631687637.154057503.block_probe_fail.crash
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,329 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: FAIL: cancelled
 2021-09-15 06:33:57,354 INFO root:39 start: subiquity/ErrorReporter/1631687637.154057503.block_probe_fail/add_info:
InterpreterPath: /snap/subiquity/2654/usr/bin/python3.6
LiveMediaBuild: Ubuntu-Server 20.04.3 LTS "Focal Fossa" - Release arm64 (20210824)
Lspci:
 00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Host bridge [1b36:0008]
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Host bridge [1af4:1100]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 
 00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Root port [1b36:000c] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

### environment

```
qemu: 
qemu-system-aarch64 --version
QEMU emulator version 4.2.0

host: 
centos7.5.1804

vm: 
ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso

virsh: 
virsh -v
4.5.0
```

### question

1. what's wrong with my installation?

- 1.1. (solved) considering crash log contains string "boot process crash at '0.000000'", I highly suspect that aarch64 simulation is wrong. How can I verify it?
- 1.2. (solved) considering crash log contains string "on physical CPU 0x000000000", I suspect that CPU option I used is wrong. How should I do?
- 1.3 Crash log contains string "block probing failed restricted=False", does that means disk of vm has some problem?

2. Should I use qemu-system-arm to create some resource before I install my VM?

Comment: It seems to suggest you don't have a disk image or something attached for the hard drive of the VM? I always work through the (unintuitive) UI of virt-manager, perhaps you can try using that to set up your VM instead of the commandline?

Comment: @rubenvb Thank you first. 1. I have the iso file on host, what does the 'device attached for' mean? 2. I can only access host by terminal.

Comment: In theory you can connect to a remote libvirtd from your computer (using virt-manager), but don't ask me how to set that up. In this case it may be better to wrangle through the commandline and not bother with the extra layer of complexity of virt-manager. I can't help you more with the qemu/ubuntu stuff though. Have you tried just doing this on your local machine?

Comment: "on physical CPU 0x000000000" is expected. This is the guest kernel telling you the MPIDR register value of the CPU it booted on, which is (very roughly speaking) its number, starting from 0. When first booted up the kernel will always be booting on CPU 0.

Comment: Can you provide the actual log, and not a screenshot of part of the log that doesn't include the strings you mention (eg "boot process crash") in your question, please?